# For a specific row, give the values and skip blank cells, in designated worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dataset with multiple rows and columns.

Example:

```
   A     B       C       D       E       F     ...
1 Name  Food 1  Food 2  Food 3  Food 4  Food 5 ...
2 Ami   Oranges Twix            Pizza   Grapes
3 Ben   Banana  Apples  Eggs            Coke
4 Mike  Peaches                 Burger  Coffee
5 Lea   Peas    Berries Cake    Chips   Sprite        
...
```

I want that data read through an array so it gives me the following:

```
Name    Food 1   Food 2  Food 4  Food 5 ...
Ami     Oranges  Twix    Pizza   Grapes
```

The food of the corresponding name but without including the blank cells or column heading.

I found a YouTube video. The code creates a new worksheet for each row.

There is a designated worksheet, within the workbook, it's supposed to appear in. Which will later be used as table in an Outlook item.

The code from YouTube:

```vb
Dim CompInfo(0 To 170, 1 To 21)
Dim r As Long, c As Long
Const StartRow As Long = 1
Dim ShNew As Worksheet
 
For r = 0 To 170
    For c = 1 To 21
        CompInfo(r, c) = Cells(r + StartRow, c).Value
    Next c
Next r
 
For r = 0 To 170
    Set ShNew = Worksheets.Add
    ShNew.Name = CompInfo(r, 2)
    
   'Setting the headers
    ShNew.Range("A1").Value = CompInfo(0, 1)
    ShNew.Range("B1").Value = CompInfo(0, 2)
    ShNew.Range("C1").Value = CompInfo(0, 3)
    ShNew.Range("D1").Value = CompInfo(0, 4)
    ShNew.Range("E1").Value = CompInfo(0, 5)
    ShNew.Range("F1").Value = CompInfo(0, 6)
    ShNew.Range("G1").Value = CompInfo(0, 7)
    ShNew.Range("H1").Value = CompInfo(0, 8)
    ShNew.Range("I1").Value = CompInfo(0, 9)
    ShNew.Range("J1").Value = CompInfo(0, 10)
    ShNew.Range("K1").Value = CompInfo(0, 11)
    ShNew.Range("L1").Value = CompInfo(0, 12)
    ShNew.Range("M1").Value = CompInfo(0, 13)
    ShNew.Range("N1").Value = CompInfo(0, 14)
    ShNew.Range("O1").Value = CompInfo(0, 15)
    ShNew.Range("P1").Value = CompInfo(0, 16)
    ShNew.Range("Q1").Value = CompInfo(0, 17)
    ShNew.Range("R1").Value = CompInfo(0, 18)
    ShNew.Range("S1").Value = CompInfo(0, 19)
    ShNew.Range("T1").Value = CompInfo(0, 20)
    ShNew.Range("U1").Value = CompInfo(0, 21)
    
    'Setting the accounts
    ShNew.Range("A2").Value = CompInfo(r, 1)
    ShNew.Range("B2").Value = CompInfo(r, 2)
    ShNew.Range("C2").Value = CompInfo(r, 3)
    ShNew.Range("D2").Value = CompInfo(r, 4)
    ShNew.Range("E2").Value = CompInfo(r, 5)
    ShNew.Range("F2").Value = CompInfo(r, 6)
    ShNew.Range("G2").Value = CompInfo(r, 7)
    ShNew.Range("H2").Value = CompInfo(r, 8)
    ShNew.Range("I2").Value = CompInfo(r, 9)
    ShNew.Range("J2").Value = CompInfo(r, 10)
    ShNew.Range("K2").Value = CompInfo(r, 11)
    ShNew.Range("L2").Value = CompInfo(r, 12)
    ShNew.Range("M2").Value = CompInfo(r, 13)
    ShNew.Range("N2").Value = CompInfo(r, 14)
    ShNew.Range("O2").Value = CompInfo(r, 15)
    ShNew.Range("P2").Value = CompInfo(r, 16)
    ShNew.Range("Q2").Value = CompInfo(r, 17)
    ShNew.Range("R2").Value = CompInfo(r, 18)
    ShNew.Range("S2").Value = CompInfo(r, 19)
    ShNew.Range("T2").Value = CompInfo(r, 20)
    ShNew.Range("U2").Value = CompInfo(r, 21)

Next r
 
End Sub
```

I also tried adding that it should not show/print those cells that are empty even if the cell above is filled.

```vb
If Range("C1").Select <> "" And Range("C2").Select = "" Then
    Range("C1:C2").Offset(0, 1).Select
End If
```

Comment: If you have office 365 use the following formula: `=FILTER(FILTER(A1:F5,(ROW(A1:F5)=1)+(A1:A5="Ami")),FILTER(A1:F5,(A1:A5="Ami"))<>"")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Export to Another Worksheet

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExportNamesAndFood()
    
    ' s - Source
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    ' d - Destination
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dFirst As String = "A2"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    If srCount < 2 Then Exit Sub ' no data or only headers
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = srg.Columns.Count
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = (srCount - 1) * 2
    
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = srg.Value
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To cCount)
    
    Dim sr As Long
    Dim sc As Long
    Dim dr As Long
    Dim dc As Long
    
    For sr = 2 To srCount
        If Len(CStr(sData(sr, 1))) > 0 Then ' name found
            ' Name
            dr = dr + 2
            dData(dr - 1, 1) = sData(1, 1)
            dData(dr, 1) = sData(sr, 1)
            ' Food
            dc = 1
            For sc = 2 To cCount
                If Not IsEmpty(sData(sr, sc)) Then ' food found
                    dc = dc + 1
                    dData(dr - 1, dc) = sData(1, sc)
                    dData(dr, dc) = sData(sr, sc)
                'Else ' food not found
                End If
            Next sc
        'Else ' no name found
        End If
    Next sr
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Range(dFirst)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dCell.Resize(dr, cCount)
    
    drg.Value = dData
    
    MsgBox "Data exported.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code. It is exactly want I was trying to do!! :)